# How to detect when dynamic WordPress content has loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm currently working on a project where our customer wants a Gallery. This gallery should be filterable through buttons above the gallery. While I believe I have found and implemented the required logic for this to work through URL-parameters and keywords in the source of the image (through various tests), my current issue is that the script is running *before* the dynamic content (images) has loaded, which means nothing really happens.

I've tried using `jQuery(document).on("ready", function() {});` , `jQuery(".gallery img").on("load", function() {});` and `jQuery(".gallery img").load(function() {});` , to no avail.

If it wasn't already obvious, the container can be accessed via **.gallery** and the images are - well - **img**.

I've already been on various StackOverflow chats where I've gotten the suggestion to move the script to after where the dynamic content is loaded in, but alas I do not know where this file is located.

Comment: Where did you found this `jQuery(document).on("ready", function() {});` ? Can you provide a link?

Comment: Right.... using `on('ready'` is not valid and hasn't been for a long time. Also...key question is if this *"dynamic content"* is being loaded asynchronously?

Comment: Use `$(window).on('load',function(){ ...  })` that shouldn't fire until all the images have loaded. Unless the images are being inserted with JS after the page has loaded. In which case you need to consult the plugin documentation. they probably have a loaded event handler

Comment: @andrew ... assuming that there is no asynchronous content being loaded ... but agree if it is all in server source

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I believe I mixed it with jQuery(document).ready(), my bad!

Comment: @charlietfl Fair enough, difficult to say but I'd guess it's being loaded asynchronously via AJAX somewhere.

Comment: @andrew Will try! Not sure why I didn't think of plugin documentation earlier, thanks!

Comment: you can check by consulting the network tab in your browser dev console. hit f12 and look at the network->xhr tab. if you see the data there, its loaded by ajax after the page has loaded

Comment: If it is being loaded by a plugin using jQuery ajax there are global ajax methods you can probably use like `$.ajaxComplete`. Need a lot more specific details to get this sorted out

Comment: @andrew Good point. It would indeed seem it is being loaded via AJAX.

Comment: You should simply delete this question since it is resolved with information not contained within the question itself and therefore has no long term value to others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the gallery is populated using Ajax requests then you can use jQuery's `.ajaxStop()` event handler. When an Ajax request is completed jQuery checks if there are any remaining requests. If there are none then the `ajaxStop` event is triggered.

Simple `ajaxStop` handler:

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
  console.log('All Ajax requests completed.')
});
```